# How can I check if a string is not equal to a certain value?

Tags: python

So here is my coding for my questionnaire so far. On the 6th line how would I make it print invalid if the user enters a random set of characters that is not 1234?

```
 print ("Welcome, Please enter your Canadian Armed Forces Identification Number")
 answer = raw_input()
 if answer == ("1234"):
     print " Please identify yourself "
 elif answer == "":
     print " Invalid ID "
     print " 3 More attempts before termination of program "
 name= raw_input()

 if answer == ("Silva"):
     print " Welcome, Silva "
```

Comment: How would I make it repeat until the correct number is right? And if the user enters it wrong 3 more times how will i make the program terminate?

Comment: Those are two different questions. I suggest you pick up a book that teaches you all the basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
if answer == ("1234"):
    print " Please identify yourself "
else:
    print " Invalid ID "
    print " 3 More attempts before termination of program " name= raw_input()
```